# Tomcat not reflecting changes in folder which is hosted outside webapps

Tags: java, tomcat, sftp

I have folder at `D:\myapp` and hosted using tomcat with `myapp.xml` at `Catalina\localhost`.

**myapp.xml content**

```
<Context path="/myapp" docBase="D:/myapp"/>
```

It's working as excepted, but it's not working when a new file is written using ftp at `D:\myapp` and i tried to access using `localhost:8080/myapp/newfile.png`.

But i can access old files, also after restarting tomcat once i can able to access that newfile.png.

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: Try this <Context path="/myapp" docBase="D:/myapp"/ reloadable="true">

Comment: @Isiva thx and it's not working... documentation says "Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes"..

Comment: you mentioned you are using myapp.xml at catalina\localhost how have you configured it? Also which version of Tomcat are you using? I checked this and it worked when I added a new image file. Where have you added the context that you created under D:/myapp?

Comment: @lsiva Thx for reply again, i have myapp.xml at apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost and version 7.0.42.

Comment: @Isiva i just created xml file with context tag and placed there at apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost folder.

Comment: rename the xml file you created under apache-tomcat-7.0.42\conf\Catalina\localhost to ROOT.xml give it a try.